# Core dumped error in dynamic programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am modifying a program that determines the fewest number of coins needed for a given amount of change. This coin system only has three coins: $0.01, $0.06, $0.10. So for 13 cents, the minimum number if coins is 3. For 56 cents, the minimum number is 6, etc. The program does that part, my part is to back trace the memo table to determine the number of each coins used. So for instance, for 13 cents the minimum is 3 coins and those coins would be 2 6-cent coins and 1 1-cent coin.

The memo table generated below looks something like:

```
1cent  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
6cent  0 1 - 3 - - - 2 - -  -  -  -  3
10cent 0 - - 3 - - - - - -  -  -  -  3
```

For something like this we always start at the bottom right. I am trying to do this recursively. I noticed a pattern. If we have a number, and the number above it is not the same number, then we "jump" over to the left of the same row `cent` spaces. So in the bottom row, the `10 cent` row, at the end we see a jump from 13 to 3 which is 10 spaces. If a number and the number above is same number, that means the coin stops being used after that many times and we move up a row. So in the table above we start at the bottom right corner, `3`. The number directly above is also a `3`, so since there have been 0 "jumps", the number of 10 cent coins used is 0 and we move up to the next row, the `6 cent` row.

Now we compare `3` and `13`. These two numbers are not equal so we move over `6` spaces. Thus we have `1` "jump" as of now. Now we look at `2` and `7`. These two are also not equal so we move over `6` more spaces and now we have `2` "jumps". Now we compare `1` and `1` and they are equal so we move up a row and start from that point. Since we had `2` "jumps" in this past row, the number of `6 cent` coins used is `2`. For this last part, it gets confusing. When we move up a row we start at the same column we were at. Since we were comparing `1` and `1`, we will resume from that column. Since this is the last row, row `0`, the amount of change left will always be the number at the top. In my example, we moved up a row and started at `1` thus the number of `1 cent` coins used is `1`. This means the total number of coins used is:

```
 1 cent: 1
 6 cent: 2
10 cent: 0
```

I know this is worded in a very confusing manner. Hopefully my code will show this better. Here is how I tried to implement this:

```
void countCoins( uint i, uint a, uint coinVal,
                 const vector< uint > & denom,
                 Matrix< uint > & memo )
{
   uint numCoins = 0;

   // Check the current value with the value above it
   if( memo.at(i, a) != memo.at(i - 1, a) )
   {
      if( denom.at(i) == coinVal )
      {
         numCoins++;
      }

      countCoins( i, a - denom.at(i), coinVal, denom, memo );    // If not equal, "jump" over
   }
   else
   {
      if( i > 0 )
      {
         countCoins( i - 1, a, coinVal, denom, memo );    // If equal, move up a row
      }
      else
      {
         numCoins += a;    // If equal and the row number is 0
      }
   }
}
```

This code compiles, but when I run it I get a message that says, "matrix.h:48: Object& Matrix::at(uint, uint) [with Object = unsigned int; uint = unsigned int]: Assertion `row < rows && col < cols' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)" and I have no idea why. Does anyone know why I would be getting this core dumped message?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your logic, but is it possible your index value for either the row or column is negative or null at some point?

Comment: Please edit your question and include a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah, I am sure my logic is hard to follow. It makes perfect sense in my head, but explaining it is difficult. I tried putting in debugging statements to print the index for the rows and columns and they seemed to be correct.

Comment: For each cell, you need to record the minimum number of coins AND the coin used to reach it.  Then you can walk back through the table starting with any chosen denomination.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `i` and `a` is less than `0` before you try to access `memo` and/or `denom`.

```
void countCoins( uint i, uint a, uint coinVal,
                 const vector< uint > & denom,
                 Matrix< uint > & memo )
{
    if (i < 0) {
        // handle edge case and return
    }

    if (a < 0) {
        // handle edge case and return
    }

    uint numCoins = 0;

    ...
    ...

}
```

Note: If `i` and `a` can have higher values than the sizes of `memo` and `denom` you need to check that also. But in your code it seems like you are always decrementing them so its probably not the case.